# How to DRY javascript code to minimize redundancy

Tags: javascript, dry

i'm  new to Javascript when it comes to DRYing code. Can someone kindly help me DRY this javascript code

This is where the JS code gets it's data from:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eMP.EMPNO, "Employee Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eMP.EMPNO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "EMPNO" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eMP.EMPNO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

And this is where the value should go:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Emp_educ.EMPNO, "EMPNO", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Emp_educ.EMPNO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "EMPNOEDUC", readOnly = "readonly" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emp_educ.EMPNO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

This is my code so far, i'm currently trying to minimize the redundancy of the code. is there are way to DRY this code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EMPNOEDUC").val($("#EMPNO").val());
    $("#EMPNOJOBHIST").val($("#EMPNO").val());
    $("#EMPNOREFERENCE").val($("#EMPNO").val());
    $("#EMPNOLICENSES").val($("#EMPNO").val());
});
```

Comment: This is a question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree with @Cid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the inputs and then you can set the value `$("#EMPNO").val()` in one line

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myinputs").val($("#EMPNO").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the target IDs in a combined jQuery selector, as follows:

```
$("#EMPNOEDUC, #EMPNOJOBHIST, #EMPNOREFERENCE, #EMPNOLICENSES").doSomething(...)
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#EMPNOEDUC, #EMPNOJOBHIST, #EMPNOREFERENCE, #EMPNOLICENSES").val($("#EMPNO").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Source:<br />
<input id="EMPNO" value="123456" /><br />
<br />
Targets:<br />
<input id="EMPNOEDUC" /><br />
<input id="EMPNOJOBHIST" /><br />
<input id="EMPNOREFERENCE" /><br />
<input id="EMPNOLICENSES" /><br />
```